# MySQL syntax error on inner join and AND value IN (Query)

Tags: mysql

I am getting a syntax error with the code below and I can't pinpoint what's wrong.

```
    SELECT contrat.nomPrenom
    FROM contrat
    WHERE Type_emploi LIKE 'Acteur'
    INNER JOIN film 
    ON contrat.ID_film = film.ID_film
    AND film.Note IN (
      SELECT Note 
      FROM film
      ORDER BY Note
      DESC
      LIMIT 1
    )
```

Comment: Where has to come after inner join. Please review https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select.html

Comment: Why would you want 'notes' ordered by note?

Comment: It's an INT, I want to return the highest note.

Answer (score 2):

```
WHERE Type_emploi LIKE 'Acteur' INNER JOIN film
```

Error is here: you have to use `INNER JOIN` before using `WHERE` clause.

Answer (score 0):

Try inner join before the where clause